# Format plaintext string into two columns that are aligned

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm looking for help with how to better organize my string output in a web app I'm developing.

The output goes to a **textarea box** and is always in this format:

`TITLE:                   Some short text here`

or

`TITLE:                   Some longer text here that might get to the end
of the line and wrap under the left column. I'd like to add the same padding
to new lines so they are neatly under the right sided text column.`

I add `.padEnd(25)` to the text in the left column, to create an even start for the right column. But I can't figure out how to keep all the text in a string longer than 50 characters aligned right under the column?

I think I need to split based on the first `space` after 50 characters, and add the 25 character left padding to each line, it might work? But I can't figure out the way to do this, so that the text looks like:

`TITLE:                   Some short text here`

`NEXT:                    Some longer text here that might get to the end
                          of the line and wrap under the left column. I'd 
                          like to add the same padding to new lines so they 
                          are neatly under the right sided text column.`

Some users will copy and paste this into their own document, so that is why I'm going through the trouble of trying to sort it out in a makeshift manner within plain text.

Thanks.

**Updated with example HTML for the User inputs**

```
<div class="input-group py-1">
    <span class="input-group-addon"> TITLE </span>
    <select class="form-control" id="ext-title">
        <option>The Hobbit</option>
        <option>Lord of the Rings</option>
        <option>Mortal Engines</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group py-1">
    <span class="input-group-addon"> NEXT </span>
    <textarea class="form-control py-1 w-100" id="ext-long" rows="3" placeholder="Specify your ideas"></textarea>
</div>
```

And sample of my script

```
var ext_title = $("#ext-title").val();
var ext_long  = $("#ext-long").val();
var text      = '';
text          +=  "\nTITLE:".padEnd(25) + ext_title +
                  "\nNEXT:".padEnd(25) + ext_long + "\n";
```

Comment: Is that input a plain multiline string? (Can you post the string definition, eg ``const input = `TITLE:     etc etc``, along with the `NEXT` part?)

Comment: The input is indeed a plain string. The left column represents categories, padded with 25 spaces, and the right column is plain text that the user enters in the app. The code looks like this: `var input = "TITLE:".padEnd(25) + userInput + "\n";`. The `userInput` is an input box or textarea where the user can type their answers.

Comment: If `userInput` can contain newlines, that could complicate things - what's your desired behavior there? Do you want to preserve them, or format the text as if the newlines (in the `userInput`) weren't there at all?

Comment: Ideally, if the text entered into `userInput` contained new lines (such as in paragraph format), then those should be preserved.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Updated my original post to show the HTML and script structure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CSS to the rescue :)

(we are JS developers after all right?)

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="section">
        <span class="title">Title</span>
        <span class="column">
            Heres my long text which needs to potentially longer that 50 characters
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <span class="title">Title</span>
        <span class="column">
            Heres my long text which needs to potentially longer that 50 characters
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS (styles.css)

```
.section {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.column {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Use margin-left to specify the distance from the titles, the words will wrap around but will stick in the column that is defined by the 'column' span

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to format the HTML into columns, I can do that with CSS as you suggested. But rather, I want to format the plaintext output of my script into a two column arrangement. This would use some combination of padding with spaces, artificial new lines and padding within the new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I messed around with a match function to create an array of text, delimited by after the 5th space (to match about 50 characters of space - I know this ain't exact). The I loop through the array, adding a pad of 25 characters before joining each item in the array back to a string.

I used this bit of code to get the effect

```
var text = $("#orig").text();

var text2 = text.match(/(.*?\s){1,5}/g);
var padded = text2[0]; // get first line

for (var i=1; i < text2.length; i++) {
    padded += "\n".padEnd(25)+text2[i]; // pad subsequent lines


var line = "TITLE:".padEnd(25) + padded +
                    "\nNEXT:".padEnd(25) + padded;

$("#new").val(line);
```

And get this output:

```
TITLE:                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                        consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin molestie 
                        leo vel odio vulputate, in 
                        tincidunt magna laoreet. Duis feugiat 
                        mi vel consequat finibus. Aenean 
                        eu tellus feugiat, rhoncus libero 
                        sed, condimentum felis.

NEXT:                   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                        consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin molestie 
                        leo vel odio vulputate, in 
                        tincidunt magna laoreet. Duis feugiat 
                        mi vel consequat finibus. Aenean 
                        eu tellus feugiat, rhoncus libero 
                        sed, condimentum felis.
```

Now I wonder if someone can help me get this into a string prototype? That way it can be invoked when needed in different parts of the code?